# Robot with Double Integrator Model

Tags: dynamics

Does the robot described by Double Integrator Model is holonomic ?

Let's say we have a robot with dynamics described by equations

\begin{cases}
\dot x = v,  &  \\
\dot v = \frac {1}{m}u
\end{cases}
Where, $x$ is the position of the robot, $v$ is the velocity and $u$ is robot's control input.

Can we call this robot a holonomic robot ?

Comment: Please expand your question so it is self-contained.

Comment: Dear robotics moderators: Please merge questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Robot with Double Integrator Model](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/12743/robot-with-double-integrator-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holonomic means that the controllable degrees of freedom in a system is equal to the total degrees of freedom.

I'm guessing you might be having difficulty differentiating between *states* and *degrees of freedom* which are both simple concepts, but sometimes confused with one another.

1st comment: The [robot] system you describe has a single degree of freedom. It just translates in a single direction like forwards and backwards. But not side to side, nor does it spin. Not a very interesting robot.

2nd comment: The double integrator has two *states*. You can assign them as

$$x_1 = x$$
and
$$x_2 =v$$
3rd comment: The system has one input, $u$, a force

So Answer: Yes, it's holonomic. There are two states (position and velocity), but only one degree of freedom and one controllable degree of freedom (forwards and backwards).

Example of a non-holonomic system: A wheel that rolls but also 'yaws' to steer a vehicle

Comment: Would a differentially steered robot (two fixed wheels on either side, usually with one or more casters) be a holonomic by your definition?